# How can I iterate through the alphabet in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I need to generate a loop that would iterate through each capital letter of the alphabet using Visual Basic (2008).  What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
...
Next
```

Comment: The ToCharArray() is not strictly necessary since strings implement IEnumerable(Of Char)

Comment: This is a very clean way to do it!

Comment: @Smith - Sample code for what?  I was only pointing out that the `ToCharArray` in the code in this answer is not required and can be omitted.

Comment: This method is useful if using a custom range:

"JKLMTUVWXYZABCDEFNOPQRSGHI"

Comment: What would the syntax be for VBA?

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way to do this would probably be:

```
For ascii = 65 To 90
    Debug.Print(Chr(ascii))
Next
```

I'm not really sure if it's the cleanest though. I haven't worked in vb.net much since I started with c#.

Comment: This gets my vote for ease of use and if you want lowercase then you can use "97 To 122" instead.

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out.  Anyone have a better solution?

To loop through the alphabet:

```
For i As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16("A"c) To Convert.ToInt16("Z"c)
        Dim letter As Char = Convert.ToChar(i)
        'Do my loop work...
Next
```

`Letter` will first equal "A", then "B", etc.

Anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to enumerate letters:

```
For Each letter As Char In Enumerable.Range(Convert.ToInt16("A"c), 26) _
                                     .Select(Function(i) Convert.ToChar(i))
    Console.WriteLine(letter)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way, but I was able to put this together in a minute.

```
 Dim alpha As String
 alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 For x = 1 To 26
      c = Mid(alpha, x, 1)
      ...
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Dim a As String
a = 65
Do
If a > 90 Then
Exit Do
Else
List1.AddItem Chr(a)
a = a + 1
End If
Loop
```

Comment: There is already another clean and short answer, what makes yours a good answer? Care to comment your code, it is more efficient than the accepted answer? Why?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to expand your commentary, right now, I see no reason this is better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Sel_1_sur_2()
Dim i As Long
Dim a As ChartObject
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Chr(65) & ":" & Chr(65))
For ascii = 65 To 90 Step 2
    Debug.Print (Chr(ascii))
    Set rng = Union(rng, Range(Chr(ascii) & ":" & Chr(ascii)))
Next
rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide a more clear picture of what this code is doing? like explain a bit

Answer (score -1):

```
Module Abecedario
    Sub main()
        Dim letra As String
        letra = 65

        Console.WriteLine("El abecedario")
        Console.WriteLine("-------------")

        Do
            If letra > 90 Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                Console.Write(Chr(letra) & ", ")
                letra = letra + 1
            End If
        Loop

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```