# VB.NET How to output From 'A' to 'ZZZ'

Tags: c#

I have seen this in c# and I'm using VB.net. This code is related somehow to what output I want to be in VB

```
string increment(string str) {        
  char[] digits = str.ToCharArray();

  for (int i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (digits[i] == 'Z') {
      digits[i] = 'A';
    } else {
      digits[i] += 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  return new string(digits);
}
```

I want to increment 'A' to 'ZZZ' just like from 0 to 999. Where the sequence is like this

```
AAA 
AAB 
AAC 
... 
AAZ
```

And after the 'AAZ' it will proceed to

```
ABA
ABC
ABD
ABE
...
ABZ
```

And so on and so fort up to 'ZZZ'

And also detects lower case or upper case

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Are you having an issue? Please tell us what it is, when it happens and what you've tried already.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+to+VB

Comment: and I'm actually confuse whether you want it to be done in VB.NET or C#.NET? in the question you mentioned want VB but you tagged C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5435024/6677731 Check this link .This may help you

Comment: i want it on VB sorry for the confusion. I'll just revise this thread in order to understand quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the VB.NET Version:

```
Private Function Increment(str As String) As String
    Dim digits As Char() = str.ToCharArray()

    For i As Integer = str.length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If digits(i) = "Z"C Then
            digits(i) = "A"C
        Else
            digits(i) = Chr(Asc(digits(i))+1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return New String(digits)
End Function
```